# Most useful free third party Android Game libraries?

Tags: android

Since I have started finding a good third party libraries for game development on android platform, Im getting confused. So want to know from the people who are already using some of the game libraries themselves (no googled resources please).

So my question is : What are some of best Android Game libraries(2D/3D)?

Note: to keep this poll as useful as possible, please remember:

When adding a new library, provide a short summary of what it does / why you think it's useful. Please make sure the answers are not repeated.

One link/source per answer is preferable.

Answer (score 4):

LibGDX - http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.php

LibGDX is a game engine with a more low-level approach. It is very fast and flexible, has a really good Box2d-JNI wrapper, and lots of extensions and tools built around it.

It is free open source software with very active developers and a helpful community, a lot of games in the market use it already.

You can run the same code on Android and on Desktop, which helps in development, as you don't have to use the emulator or adb too often, which helps with turn-around times.

There is even a tool to fetch input events on your phone while using the desktop-version of your game, so you can develop and test control schemes fast too. ( https://market.android.com/details?id=com.badlogic.gdx.remote )

Answer (score 2):

http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/

Extremely easy to use. Has BOX2d implemented in an easy to use way. Can build native IOS and Android applications.